# Is there a way to find all Logins, and all database users this login have?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to join, every login and permissions tables. Looking over the internet but I just can't find something to list like:

```
LOGIN  |  USER  | DATABASE_THE_USER_HAS_ACCESS
```

This is because I would like to find all users with not a single permission on any database ( Login with no users ).

```
sys.server_principals AS log
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.syslanguages AS l ON l.name = log.default_language_name
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_permissions AS sp ON sp.grantee_principal_id = log.principal_id and sp.type = N'COSQ'
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.credentials AS c ON c.credential_id = log.credential_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN master.sys.certificates AS cert ON cert.sid = log.sid
LEFT OUTER JOIN master.sys.asymmetric_keys AS ak ON ak.sid = log.sid
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.sql_logins AS sqllog ON sqllog.principal_id = log.principal_id
WHERE
```

I'm looking at these tables but I can't find a pattern to join them,.

Comment: You could write an outer join directly to `<eachdb>.sys.database_principals` if you know all the replacement values for `<eachdb>` (or dump all of those into a #temp table). If you don't, you'll need to generate it with dynamic SQL.

Comment: Found this - https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1894659/How-to-list-all-database-Users-without-Logins which can get you started.

Comment: Yeah, just [please don't use `sp_MSforeachdb`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlserverauthor/49/aaron-bertrand/). I wish I could do an entire Internet search and replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, go grab `sp_foreachdb` from the First Responder Kit ([background here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlserverauthor/49/aaron-bertrand/)):

- [SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/sp_foreachdb.sql](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/sp_foreachdb.sql)

Then you can collect all the database users here:

```
CREATE TABLE #DBUsers
(
  DBName sysname,
  DBUserName sysname,
  DBPrincipalID int,
  SID varbinary(85),
  LoginName nvarchar(128),
  LoginPrincipalID int
);

EXEC master.dbo.sp_foreachdb N'INSERT #DBUsers 
SELECT ''?'',d.name, d.principal_id, d.sid, s.name, s.principal_id
FROM ?.sys.database_principals AS d
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_principals AS s 
ON d.sid = s.sid
WHERE d.principal_id > 4 
  AND d.type <> ''R''
  AND d.name NOT LIKE N''##%##'';';
```

Now for example to find any server-level login that doesn't have an associated user in *any* database (note this will currently include those in elevated roles, like `sysadmin`):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals AS p
WHERE type NOT IN ('S','R','C')
  AND name NOT LIKE N'##%##' 
  AND name NOT LIKE N'NT %\%'
  AND NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM #DBUsers
    WHERE SID = p.sid
  );
```

Note that you might have to dig a bit deeper, because a user might have been added to a database to explicitly *deny* access. But that should be a good start for the normal case.

Comment: Yeeeah Thanks Aaron. ...I already have this SP_FOREACHDB for a loooong time. It worked . haha thanks again.